# How to change the 3 in {0:f3} to an int from user input

Tags: c#

**Solved, thanks for the help!**

So I got an assignment for school, and no matter how much I search the net or read my books I can't figure out the answer to the question.

I have done programming for about 4 hours, so thats why the question is phrased wierdly, I think.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number with any number of decimals.");
string input;
input = Console.ReadLine();
decimal myNumber = decimal.Parse(input); 

Console.WriteLine("Please specify how many decimals you want to be shown.");
string input2;
input22 = Console.ReadLine();
int myDecimal = int.Parse(input2);

Console.WriteLine(("Your number with the choosen number of decimals: {0:f3}"), myNumber);
```

So, when I run it and enter 2,1234567 as my number and 5 as my number of decimals, it prints 2,123 instead of 2,12345.

I know it prints 3 decimals because of the 3 after the f, but I can't figure out how to change the 3 into the ammount chosen by the user.

I have tried `{0:f(myDecimal)}`, `{myDecimal:f` and `{0:f(int = myDecimal)}` , none of which I expected to work as I was just testing things out.

The answer is probably really simple, and I'm probably just overthinking things, but help would be very much appriciated!

Comment: A format string is just that, a _string_.  Have you tried creating a format string that uses the number the user enters?

Comment: Check out [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Do *not* update your question to include "solved" in the title or body. Instead, mark and answer as *accepted*. You also "thank" people who answered your question by up-voting their answers (as well as accepting the *best* answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need a format-ception here:

```
// the {{ and }} escapes to { and }
var numberFormat = string.Format("{{0:f{0}}}", myDecimal).Dump();
Console.WriteLine("Your number with the choosen number of decimals: " + numberFormat, myNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just simply change your last `Console.WriteLine()` call to this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your number with the choosen number of decimals: {0}",
                  myNumber.ToString("f" + input2));
```

The part that changes is: `myNumber.ToString("f" + input2)`.  What this does is use string concatenation to *build* your format string from your variable `input2`.

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HBDF2m).

Please keep in mind though, the format string you are using ("F") will *round* to that number of decimal places (i.e `1.236` would become `1.24` with format `"F2"`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ToString too

```
decimal myNumber = 224323.545656M;
int myDecimal = 4;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Your number with the choosen number of decimals: {0} " , myNumber.ToString("F" + myDecimal)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the format string dynamically. At this point using a substituted string is harder than `ToString`:

```
var digits = 3;
var input = 2.123456789;
var format = $"F{digits}";

var output = "Some text {input.ToString(format)} some more text";
```